# Where to buy US repatriation and evacuation insurance only?

Tags: insurance, j1-visas

I am traveling to the US on a J-1 visa. My university provides medical insurance, but no emergency evacuation or repatriation, both of which are mandatory for the J-1. Where can I buy these two separately, i.e. without any health insurance?

Comment: This isn't an expats question - J1 is a non-immigrant short-term visa.  Moving to travel.

Comment: @MarkMayo Hmm, my searching says J1 status can be valid for up to 7 years, I wouldn't call that short-term.

Comment: @PeterGreen - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-1_visa - looks like for the most part, they're short term (Certainly was the two times I've had one), depending on the subclass. Eg camp counselor, intern, work/travel, short-term scholar, but can be longer depending on the sub category. It's definitely categorised as a non-immigrant visa, though, so I still feel it doesn't fit for expats.

Answer (score 6):

There are insurers that offer coverage for medical evacuation and repatriation, and many designed for J visa holders. Here are the results of a Google search on 'J1 medical evacuation and repatriation insurance:'

[Visitor Guard](http://www.visitorguard.com/exchange-visa-insurance/)

[J1 Visa Insurance](https://www.j1visainsurance.net/)

[Envisage International Student Insurance](https://www.internationalstudentinsurance.com/j1student/insurance-requirements-j1-visa.php)

[American Visitor Insurance](https://www.americanvisitorinsurance.com/visa-insurance/j1-visa.asp)

[Cigna](https://www.cignaglobal.com/health-insurance-plans/international-emergency-evacuation-insurance?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIlbnCueXW1QIVRySBCh3m0gj4EAAYAiAAEgJtC_D_BwE)

[DIANins Global](http://www.dianins.com/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIlbnCueXW1QIVRySBCh3m0gj4EAAYASAAEgIFC_D_BwE)

[Allianz](https://www.allianzworldwidecare.com/en/international-expat-health-insurance/benefits-2/?_bt=187371903279&_bk=%2Binsurance%20%2Brepatriation&_bm=b&_bn=g&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIlbnCueXW1QIVRySBCh3m0gj4EAAYBCAAEgI0vfD_BwE)

Before buying separately, you might contact the insurer(s) available through the university. It may have such coverage and be able to add to your policy, and possibly for less than paying for independent coverage.

Disclaimer: I have no affiliation with any insurance providers, I do have a relative in management at Alphabet Inc.